# cloudstack api signing with visual basic

Tags: api, vb.net-2010, sign, apache-cloudstack, cloud-platform

Really hoping somebody can help me out here.
I've made a little program in vb.net which will interact with the Cloudstack i've recently deployed.

At the minute its declining my API calls straight away as 401 unauthorized, so i'm obviously not generating my signature properly.

I've pulled the bit from the documentation which explains how to generate the signature to sign requests... you can view that here: http://www.x85.co.uk/generatesig.txt

I've used an example function i found online to get the SHA1 hash, but nowhere in this code does it have the secret key, so thats a problem...

```
Function getSHA1Hash(ByVal strToHash As String) As String
Dim sha1Obj As New Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider
Dim bytesToHash() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strToHash)
bytesToHash = sha1Obj.ComputeHash(bytesToHash)
Dim strResult As String = ""
For Each b As Byte In bytesToHash
    strResult += b.ToString("x2")
Next
Return strResult
End Function
```

I also havent included the URL encode bit as i'm not sure how to do this.

Any help is appriciated.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try the [CloudStack .NET SDK NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CloudStack.SDK/)

Calculates the signature for you and works VB.NET

Here's a rough sample usage in C#.  Hopefully you can translate it to VB:

```
var cloudStackClient = new Client(csApiUrl, csApiKey, csApiSecret);

CloudStack.SDK.APIRequest req = new APIRequest("deleteTemplate");
req.Parameters.Add("id", id);
cloudStackClient.SendRequest(req);
```